# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'

Tags: python, typeerror

my message is:

```
message = {
        "msgtype":"markdown",
        "markdown":{
            "title":"aliyun warning",
            "text":content
        },
        "at":{
            "atMobiles":["%s"] % phone_number,
            "isAtAll": false
        }
    }
```

phone_number is a param,when i send it,raise this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'

how to fix this error?

Comment: `"atMobiles":["%s"] % phone_number` -> `"atMobiles":["%s" % phone_number]` The error is straightforward: %-formatting is a string formatting, and your string is in the list, so formatting also has to be inside

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code service website..
Also why not just `[phone_number]`

Answer (score 0):

This is an invalid Python expression:

```
["%s"] % phone_number
```

You probably want something like the following instead:

```
[phone_number]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, type error  did not appear again